\copy PSQL give the error: no such file or directory
I'm trying to copy a csv file in a table using PSQL tool but i receive the error: no such file or directory.
This is the command:
\copy company_dim FROM 'C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Data Studio\company_dim.csv/company_dim.csv' WITH (FORMAT csv, HEADER true, DELIMITER ',', ENCODING 'UTF8')
I already saw other similar questions around, but no proposed solution seems to work. (i specify, the error is just "no such file or directory" not "could not connect to server...")
To have more information: i'm following Luke Barousse's Youtube course on SQL. What i did  should solve a permission problem from VScode, but it results in this other issue.
I literally followed the problem solution proposed, which is:
Database Load Issues (follow if receiving permission denied when running SQL code below)
NOTE: If you are having issues with permissions. And you get error:
'could not open file "[your file path]\job_postings_fact.csv" for reading: Permission denied.'

Open pgAdmin
In Object Explorer (left-hand pane), navigate to sql_course database
Right-click sql_course and select PSQL Tool

This opens a terminal window to write the following code


Get the absolute file path of your csv files

Find path by right-clicking a CSV file in VS Code and selecting �Copy Path�


Paste the following into PSQL Tool, (with the CORRECT file path)

I changed the position of the csv folder; I changed the permissions of the files; I tried to change the console code page; i set the windows path for postgreSQL. I tried the command "copy" instead of "\copy".
Also tried changing \ with /.

Look at the path delimiters in this C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Data Studio\company_dim.csv/company_dim.csv', they switch direction. I would try using all /.

Just tried, it shows the same error

Then I'm guessing the user you are running psql as does not have permissions on at least one of the directories in the PATH. It is not enough to give permissions on the file itself, the user needs permissions all the way down the PATH.

I'm sorry but i still don't know much about this field. Can you please tell me more or less how to do that? Thank you for your answer

Ok, i don't know precisely what solved it, but it's solved. I just restarted the whole process from the beginning. ( i used "" as path delimiters again, and it worked).
